# VMware ESXi old releases

Tags: vmware, esxi

I'm interested in the history of ESXi, to see how it evolved during every major update.

However the earliest release I was able to get is version 5.5

Does anyone know of an archive, ftp mirror, website etc... for old ESXi releases?

I've found version 3 on Arhive.org, unfortunately it's incomplete.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[VMware ESXi Release and Build Number History](https://www.virten.net/vmware/esxi-release-build-number-history/#esxi7.0)

[Download VMware ESXi 4.X](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?baseCode=ZCV0YmRoaHBiZHdldA==)

[Download VMware ESXi 3.5](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vi/esxi3.5)

Comment: Thanks for the links but whenever I try to download I need to logon with my vmware account, I only have permission to download the latest edition (7.0) as a trail. Only if you have bought it on your account you can download it apparently

Comment: @JensVde - In order to use any version of ESXi you will need a license for that specific version.  I was able to download all versions of ESXi without an issue after logging into my account.  *We will be unable to link to any version that cannot be downloaded directly from VMWare.*

Comment: @Ramhound how can I apply or get those licences for products that are no longer sold? I'm really looking for versions prior to 4 etc those are discontinued a long time ago. I'm just a student

Comment: You could try to get in touch with VMware by this link: [https://www.vmware.com/company/contact_sales.html](https://www.vmware.com/company/contact_sales.html)

Comment: @JensVde - VMWare as most companies do only offer the current version for purchase.  It’s extremely unlikely, cows learning to fly is more likely, they will sell you the required license to an older ESXi release.